# clang-analyzer: scan-build ./configure fails looking for pthread support: "_REENTRANT must be defined"

Tags: c, clang, pthreads, github-actions, clang-static-analyzer

I'm using pthreads and my scan-build action has failed:

https://github.com/SentryPeer/SentryPeer/runs/5034401493?check_suite_focus=true

I see this:

```
cat clang_output_*
conftest.c:59:26: error: "_REENTRANT must be defined"
#                        error "_REENTRANT must be defined"
                         ^
```

and

```
checking whether /usr/bin/../libexec/ccc-analyzer is Clang... rm: cannot remove 'conftest.plist': Is a directory
no
checking whether pthreads work with "-pthread" and "-lpthread"... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthreads... no
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work with -mthreads... no
checking for the pthreads library -lpthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with --thread-safe... no
checking whether pthreads work with -mt... no
checking for pthread-config... no
configure: error: POSIX threads support is required
scan-build: Analysis run complete.
scan-build: Removing directory '/tmp/scan-build-2022-02-02-202911-1481984-1' because it contains no reports.
scan-build: No bugs found.
```

Version:
clang-analyzer-13.0.0-3.fc35.noarch

My autotools builds fine without scan-build on the same Ubuntu version, as per:

https://github.com/SentryPeer/SentryPeer/actions/runs/1783127976

Any tips here? Not sure if this is a bug nor where to ask. I've raised it here too - https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53552

Thanks for reading,
Gavin.

Comment: The same happens when doing scan-build ./configure on libsodium and jq projects, so not just my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_REENTRANT` is an obsolete [feature-test macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) recognized at one time by Glibc and some other C implementations.  The supported use case for this macro is for the *user* to define it in their source code or on the compiler command line to request features or behavior that otherwise might not be provided.

The `configure` script you are using seems to be trying to determine whether pthreads support has successfully been enabled by checking whether `_REENTRANT` has been defined.  However, this has always been questionable because it depends on undocumented implementation details of the C library and compiler.  It worked at one time, for some C implementations, but it does not work with the C implementation you are now using.  I would account that a flaw in `clang-static-analyzer`.

Comment: Thanks John. I'll update the issue I've opened and try to to dig into the Perl source of scan-build.